# $F(p)=(F_1(p),...F_r(p))$ smooth map, Why is it true that $dF_p(X_p)=(X_p(F_1),...,X_p(F_r))$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $F:M\to \Bbb R^r$,smooth map, dim(M)=m

s.t $F(p)=(F_1(p),...F_r(p))$
so  the components are $F_k:M\to \Bbb R$

Why is it true that

**$dF_p(X_p)=(X_p(F_1),...,X_p(F_r))$?**

**I've trying to prove it without success and I also searched in Lee's smooth manifolds book, but I can't find this result.Any help is appreaciated.**

[image]

Comment: $n$ should be $r$. It holds by definition for $r=1$. After that, it’s just that you differentiate vector-valued functions component by component. Maybe you need to review multivariable analysis.

Comment: @TedShifrin I fixed the typo. This is an abstract vector  $X_p$ with domain in M, Can you please elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: In coordinates it is true that $DF(x) =  \begin{pmatrix} DF_1(x) \\ \vdots \\ DF_n(x) \\ \end{pmatrix}$, so it's natural to define the same to hold on the manifold. It's not something you prove unless you defined the derivative of vector valued $F$ somehow already.

Comment: @Mason I was trying to use eq 3.9, see above without success, Was that the way to go? Also I see your vector is a column vector, but my expression is a row vector?

Comment: Just evaluate $dF_p(\partial/\partial x^i)$ at $y^j$. This extracts the $j$th coefficient.

Comment: Since $F$ is vector-valued, you should be writing a column vector, not a row vector. Back to the original. If $X$ is a vector field on $M$, we define $Xf$ to be the function whose value at $p$ is $X_pf$. How is that defined?

Comment: @William Thanks for the suggestion, See my answer, looks good?

Comment: @TedShifrin  $X_pf$ is a function that results from applying the derivation X_p to f, so I am not sure what do you mean by " how is it defined". And how did you have in mind that that would help in the answering this?

Comment: The coordinate-free definition of $X_pf$ is precisely the directional derivative $Df_p(X_p)$. So yes, it's relevant.

Comment: @TedShifrin So how can I prove the result, in a coordinate-free way?

Comment: I just did. Of course you have to apply it component-wise to the vector-valued function. There’s no getting around that.

Answer (score 2):

Write $X_p=X_p^{(i)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p$

Following William's suggestion and using eq 3.9:

$dF_p(X_p)
=dF_p(X_p^{(i)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p)
=X_p^{(i)}dF_p(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p) 
=X_p^{(i)}\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}|_{F(p)} 
=(X_p^{(i)}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}_p) F^j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}|_{F(p)}
= X_pF^j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}|_{F(p)}=(X_pF^1,...,X_pF^r)$